# "Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory for 'GestureDetector.tsx' in 'react-native-gesture-handler'"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I'm encountering an issue in my React Native project related to the GestureDetector.tsx file in the react-native-gesture-handler package. The specific error message I'm receiving
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/handlers/gestures/GestureDetector.tsx'
I have confirmed that the react-native-gesture-handler package is present in the node_modules directory, but the mentioned file is missing from the package.

I have already taken several steps to resolve the issue, including:

Verifying the presence of the react-native-gesture-handler package in the node_modules directory
Clearing the package cache using npm cache clean --force (or yarn cache clean)
Deleting the node_modules directory and reinstalling packages using npm install (or yarn install)
Checking the dependencies in my package.json file and ensuring compatibility with React Native
Despite these efforts, the issue still persists. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the Metro bundler cache can cause issues. Try clearing the Metro cache by running: npm start -- --reset-cache, you can try removing your node_modules folder and your package-lock.json or yarn.lock file, and then reinstalling all dependencies using npm install or yarn install.